# Change Curtin University Websites Region Settings When Using requests

Tags: python, python-requests, python-requests-html

I am trying to get some information about courses in
https://www.curtin.edu.au/study/offering/course-ug-chemical-engineering-major-beng-hons--mjrh-cheng/
using python and requests.
This websites defaults to Domestic as the region when using `requests` library to get the html code.

I cannot find a way to change it to international and vice versa. Is there any way to do this?
(I cannot use selenium, though can use MiniRacer)

This is the code I currently use

```
def get_response(url, **kwargs):
    try:
        return requests.get(url,  headers=headers, **kwargs)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error : {e}\nRetrying in 5s")
        time.sleep(5)
        return get_response(url, **kwargs)
```

**Edit :**

I found out that manually changing the region updates

```
<script>
    dataCoreLayer = [{
        'fsTaughtBy': 'WASM: Minerals, Energy and Chemical Engineering (WASM-MECE)',
        'fsStudyLvl': 'undergraduate',
        'fsIntDom': 'dom',  <----- This value (int, dom)
        'fsUdc': 'MJRH-CHENG',
        'fsCourseTitle': 'Chemical Engineering Major (BEng Hons)',
        'fsFaculty': 'N/A',
    }];

    offeringData = {
        'studyLevel': 'undergraduate',
        'seoURL': 'course-ug-chemical-engineering-major-beng-hons--mjrh-chengv2'
    }
</script>
```

in index html.

Not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to change the version of the page to `dom` or `int`. You can do that by setting the correct cookie parameter:

```py
import requests

url = "https://www.curtin.edu.au/study/offering/course-ug-chemical-engineering-major-beng-hons--mjrh-cheng/"
cookies = {"has_seen_personalisation": "true", "segment": "dom"}

text = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies).text
print(text)
```

Prints `dom` version of the page. If you set the `"segment"` to `int` it will get international version.

Comment: Thank you very much, It worked, can you explain how you found this out?

Comment: @LittleMAN I've looked at Web Developer Tools->Network Tab. Refreshed the page at inspect what information is sent to the server (cookies and http headers are among the informations the client is sending to the server).